# Istio labels mismatch

Tags: kubernetes, istio

While installing istio using `istioctl` command, a set of labels is generated and applied for most of the resources that are not there if I compare it with the generated `istioctl manifest generate`. Does anybody knows what is the usage of these labels or if they are required at all?

```
labels:
  install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: istiocontrolplane-1-10-0
  install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource-namespace: istio-system
  operator.istio.io/managed: Reconcile
  operator.istio.io/version: 1.10.0
```

For `install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource` is actually generated by `istioctl manifest generate` but with value “unknown” instead of the one provided by the patching (-f) istiooperatorinstall .yaml file.

The definition of those labels is seen [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/operator/pkg/helmreconciler/common.go#L33), but its usage when not using an operator is uncertain to me.

[Istio Operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator?_ga=2.10293110.218655273.1623666080-732764254.1619440338) is not installed in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no reasoning behind those labels to be found anywhere, at least I could not find any information. Therefore the below is opinion based.*

When you decide to install such operator at some point, those labels could help the operator to bring existing infrastructure to a desired level based on operator CRDs instead of creating a second layer of istio mesh.

---

**EDIT**

There is [Istio resource deletion can't trigger operator reconcile #23603](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23603) issue on GitHub, that may explain those labels.

Comment: I'm more and more convinced now that those labels are not relevant if no operator is present. In my case, I'm deploying now using istioctl generated manifests via argocd, where those manifests have no labels of "operator". Everything seems to work just fine. I did need those labels when testing upgrading with operator (another test).